# Slow Redis Cluster GET performance for large (>100kB) objects

Tags: redis, cassandra

I'm trying to use Redis Cluster as a backing cache for a primary datastore (Cassandra). I've noticed that, while Redis is significantly faster than Cassandra for fetching small objects, it falls behind for objects larger than 100kB.

My questions are:

1. Is Redis or Redis Cluster known to have performance issues when dealing with large objects?
2. Are there ways to optimize Redis Cluster for the storage of primarily large objects?
3. Is this indicative of a weakness in Redis or a known strength in Cassandra - does it line up with benchmarks comparing the two services?

Based on Yourkit profiling, the slowness seems to occur during either the network connection between Redis and the client or within Redis itself, not on the client side. Results from iperf show normal throughput for a 1Gb/s connection, and latency between the machines is sub-millisecond. SLOWLOG shows nothing out of the ordinary.

Some facts about my Redis Cluster:
18 instances spread out across 3 VMs with a replication factor of 1 (so 9 masters total and 6 instances on each VM).
Each VM has 32GB of memory, and each instance uses 5GB. Each VM has 4 cores.
Both forms of persistence (RDB and AOF) are disabled.
Transparent Huge Pages are disabled.

Below I've included a table illustrating how throughput falls off with increasing object size. Tests on both Cassandra and Redis were run single threaded with a single connection for each.

> Redis throughput: 0.003537595276169634 MB/s, Cassandra throughput:
>   0.002188710038885119 MB/s, object size in bytes: 10, throughput ratio: 1.6162923426675595
>
> Redis throughput: 0.03797119469182343 MB/s, Cassandra throughput:
>   0.02551391762038427 MB/s, object size in bytes: 100, throughput ratio: 1.4882541856875189
>
> Redis throughput: 0.3897608379431817 MB/s, Cassandra throughput:
>   0.2901892901215633 MB/s, object size in bytes: 1000, throughput ratio: 1.3431261980065041
>
> Redis throughput: 2.7464192980834445 MB/s, Cassandra throughput:
>   2.5417614833282105 MB/s, object size in bytes: 10000, throughput ratio: 1.080518103723585
>
> Redis throughput: 7.020086815887924 MB/s, Cassandra throughput:
>   12.797994158989074 MB/s, object size in bytes: 100000, throughput ratio: 0.5485302406515904
>
> Redis throughput: 19.84828274884104 MB/s, Cassandra throughput:
>   44.10034458329361 MB/s, object size in bytes: 1000000, throughput ratio: 0.45007092203901056

The only noticeable difference in the network configuration is that the Cassandra cluster is composed of physical machines whereas the Redis cluster is composed of VMs. But it seems like that shouldn't account for a 50% slowdown, especially when Redis is reading from memory and Cassandra is (at least occasionally) reading from disk.

Any help would be appreciated!